# Find all ReLU layer in a torchvision model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

After I fetch a pre-trained model from `torchvision.models`, I want all the `ReLU` instance to `register_backward_hook(f)`,which is like this:

```
for pos, module in self.model.features._modules.items():
    for sub_module in module:
        if isinstance(module, ReLU):
            module.register_backward_hook(f)
```

The problems for me is how to find all `ReLU` in a model. For `densenet161`, the `ReLU` exists not only in `model.features._modules` but also in self-defined dense layer, eg. `model.features._modules['denseblock1'][0]`. For  `resnet151`, the `ReLU` exists in `model._modules` and its self-define layer, eg `model._modules['layer1']`.

Is there any way to find all `ReLU` inside a model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more elegant way to iterate over all components of a model is using [`modules()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.modules)
method:

```
from torch import nn

for module in self.model.modules():
  if isinstance(module, nn.ReLU):
    module.register_backward_hook(f)
```

If you do not want to get all sub-modules, only the immediate ones, you may consider using [`children()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.children) method instead of `modules()`. You can also get the name of the sub module using [`named_modules()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.named_modules) method.